# How to programmatically check for and retrieve a contract's proxy or implementation address?

Tags: etherscan, web3.py, proxy-contracts

Can I use the etherscan API or some other method, to programmatically check for and retrieve a  contract's proxy or implementation address, if it has one?

For example, when building contract objects with `web3.py`, I need to use the proxy contract's address, but the implementation contract's ABI. Is there a service that allows me to find one or the other programmatically?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this?